# What is the thing outside of the window that cover the base/sill?

Tags: windows, sill

[image]

[image]

This is the picture of what I saw on the outside of my window. The outmost layer is my vinyl siding, then it's asphalt and the wood. There needs to be something covering this part in case of rain? I am a new owner, so I don't know what I need to order from Home Depot. What is the name of the items that i need to order?

And the following pictures have two windows, the pictures above are taken from the window on the right. The left one is a good one.[image]

Comment: Is this looking up, down, or sideways?

Comment: Can you take another photo and zoom out a bit.

Comment: @HotLicks It is looking down

Comment: @PlatinumGoose just took another photo. check it again

Comment: Not sure what the piece is called, someone else will probably come along and answer. You should be able to find it at one of the big box stores just match the one under the AC unit.

Comment: @PlatinumGoose It is not AC related. but is it possible to be a window sill? It's been like that since I moved in half year ago. Do I need to worry about water damage?

Comment: No it is not AC related but the window with the AC unit has one. It is a sill but that's kind of a generic term, there's probably a more specific name for one for vinyl siding. You should have one there to prevent water from getting behind the siding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's just a sill wrap. When maintenance-free siding was installed all the old trim needed to be covered and extended for appearance and weather handling. Looks like the wind decided to pull it off for you, or someone bumped it while trying to escape. It could be laying around somewhere or stored in the garage rafters.

There's nothing to order. It's a custom-built part formed on site by a siding installer using a sheet metal "brake" and hand tools. You can study that type of project and tackle it yourself, or you can take careful measurements and ask a shop to make you one, or you can hire someone.

Be aware that the sill is usually one of the first things wrapped when siding is installed, so it fits behind other components like the J-channel. Usually it's quite securely held.

Comment: So my window is also missing an exteior sill? I showed the pictures to the Home Depot guy, he said those are aluminum sheet bended by a machine

Comment: Sometimes there's nothing inside. Depends on what trim the house was initially fitted with and whether it was rotted away when it was resided.

Comment: So If i buy a piece of aluminium to cover this part, will it be good enough?

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking me. :P

Comment: i am asking if I need an exterior window sill

Comment: Do you mean a _wood_ sill? Not really. As I said, these things are commonly partially or completely hollow. You sometimes see support blocks at the corners and every so often to give a little strength. They're mostly decorative.

Comment: Yes,  like the wood sill like the interior one in the picture. I don't need an exterior one.